# Notifications not working in Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

I'm not entirely sure this is the right place, but here goes.

On an Android One device (Xiaomi Mi A1) with Android 8.1 I do not receive notifications. They are enabled in app settings, in system as well. When I log in there are new in-SE notifications in the form of a red number in upper right hand corner.

My best guess is that this is connected to more aggressive background optimizations in newer Android versions. For reference I receive Facebook Messenger messages properly and sleep tracking in Sleep as Android works as well.

Comment: Have you ever received SE notifications on any phone? This may be a duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314204/389569.

Comment: @JasonBassford will try it first and confirm. I migrated from an LG G5 where they worked (Android 7)

Comment: @JasonBassford now I only need a trigger if you could.

Comment: Here you go. ;)

Comment: @JasonBassford this was a duplicate question then.

Comment: I'm glad that fixed the problem.